# Set multiple x-and y-limits by group for base plot

Tags: r, plot

I need to set different limits for different sets of x and y values. I used the following code:

```
if (names(df[1]) == "Apple") {
  xlim=c(10, 77)
}
if (names(df[1]) == "Orange") {
  xlim=c(22 ,55)
}
if (names(df[1]) == "Watermelon") {
  xlim=c(63, 97)
}
```

I have many x values that I need to set the respective x-limits. Is there any smart way of doing this instead of writing the if conditions one by one?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add the x-limits to your dataframe? 

Something along these lines:
if(names(df[1])=="Apple"){
    xlim=df[2]}

Comment: @martsc1 I will use the base R plot function with the limit set. So I won't create a new column as the limit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather define the limits in the subset using `points` on an empty `plot`.

```
plot(y ~ x, d, type="n")
points(y ~ x, d[d$nm == "Apple" & d$x %in% 10:77, ], col="red", pch=20)
points(y ~ x, d[d$nm == "Orange" & d$x %in% 22:55, ], col="green", pch=20)
points(y ~ x, d[d$nm == "Watermelon" & d$x %in% 63:97, ], col="blue", pch=20)
```

#### Result

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
d <- data.frame(nm=rep(c("Apple", "Orange", "Watermelon"), each=2e3),
           x=sample(1:100, 6e3, replace=T),  y=rnorm(6e3))
```